# Formatting JSON data from iron-form

Tags: json, ajax, polymer

I'm using iron-form to send data to a Rails server. Currently the form is sending JSON similar to this:

```
{
  "date": "January 1",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "company": "Whatever Inc."
}
```

But in order to receive it on the Rails end I need it to be formatted like this:

```
{
  "userInfo": {
    "date": "January 1",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "company": "Whatever Inc."
  }
}
```

How do I nest the form data within the `userInfo` param? I tried using the `iron-form-presubmit` event listener but couldn't make it work.

Here is the code for my iron-form:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="url/for/api">
  <input name="date" is="iron-input">
  <input name="name" is="iron-input">
  <input name="company" is="iron-input">

  <div id="buttons">
    <paper-button id="submit" raised onclick="_submit(event)">Save</paper-button>
    <paper-button id="reset" raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset </paper-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>

Polymer({
  is: 'my-view1',
});

function _submit(event) {
    var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    form.submit();
}

function _reset(event) {
    var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    form.reset();
}

</script>
```

Comment: could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal I added the code to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my understanding you could update the request body before the data gets submitted and transform the current data into an object/structure of your liking:

```
<form is="iron-form" on-iron-form-presubmit="_presubmit" id="form" method="post" action="url/for/api">
  <input name="date" is="iron-input">
  <input name="name" is="iron-input">
  <input name="company" is="iron-input">

  <div id="buttons">
    <paper-button id="submit" raised onclick="_submit(event)">Save</paper-button>
    <paper-button id="reset" raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset </paper-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

similar to how its done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852973/modify-iron-form-json-before-submitting), but changing the body entirely

```
function _presubmit(e) {
  let body = this.$.form.request.body;
  body = {"userInfo" : body };
}
```

Hope this helps a lil.

Comment: Now it's returning this:

`Parameters: {"userInfo"=>"[object Object]"}`

Any idea why?

Comment: @LauraM that looks about right, if you're console.loggin that you need to JSON.stringify() it to see it because its a nested object