# Polymer paper-tags-input not added to form

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Trying to include an array field in a POST request with [paper-tags-input](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/polymerEl/paper-tags).

The form is set up as follows:

```
<paper-dialog id="dialog" modal class="size-position">
<iron-form id="myForm" on-iron-form-response="_formResponse">
  <form method="post" enctype="application/json" action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/items">

    <paper-input name="owner" label="Owner"></paper-input>

    <paper-tags-input name="tags" label="Tag(s)" duplicate-error-message="Duplicate">
    </paper-tags-input>

    <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button raised dialog-dismiss class="cancel">
            Cancel
        </paper-button>
        <paper-button raised dialog-confirm autofocus on-tap="_submit" class="submit">
            Submit
        </paper-button>
    </div>

  </form>
</iron-form>
</paper-dialog>
...
<script>
    ...
    _submit() {
        this.$.myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

While `paper-input` field named `owner` is included in the request payload, there is nothing getting added for `tags` in the request payload.

How to get the values in the `tags` array field included in the POST request payload?

If the above is not possible, then I think an alternative solution would be to declare a new property called `tags_list` and set it as the `tags` attribute for `paper-tags-input`, like:

```
<paper-tags-input name="tags" 
        label="Tag(s)" 
        duplicate-error-message="Duplicate"
        tags="{{tags_list}}">
</paper-tags-input>
```

Then I see the values are available in `this.tags_list`, which I can access in the `submit()` function. How can I add that to `myForm` before I do the submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this with the second approach.

Took hint from: [Modify iron-form JSON before submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852973/modify-iron-form-json-before-submitting)

Added a presubmit to iron form like this:

```
<iron-form id="myForm" 
    on-iron-form-presubmit="_preSubmit" 
    on-iron-form-response="_formResponse">
...
<script>
  _preSubmit() {
      var body = this.$.myForm.request.body;
      body['tags'] = [];
      this.tags_list.forEach(function(tag) {
          body['tags'].push({"name": tag});
      });
  }
</script>
```

Actually this approach is what I might need, since I need to modify the array values and keep each value as an object anyway.